# Would allocating the length of an array inside a struct, with one of the member variables of the struct, work?

Tags: c

I am trying to create an array inside a struct as follows:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) INIT_HEADER
{
    uint16_t rounter_n;
    uint16_t update_interval;
    uint16_t router_IDs[rounter_n];
    ...
    ...   
}
```

This will actually be cast on a string from which I will extract each field individually. The string would have that many router_IDs (and other details) as the number of routers.

Basically, the first 32-bit is non-repetitive. The rest is repetitive and is repeated as many times as the number of routers. Refer below image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBIFR.png)

I want to be able to create a struct that can effectively be cast on this string, depending on the number of routers.

Comment: That won't compile. The closest thing to that that current C offers are flexible array members. Basically you'd need to make `uint16_t router_IDs[];` the last member (like this, with the empty brackets) and then make sure the allocated storage space underneath it is at least `sizeof(INIT_HEADER) + sizeof(uint16_t)*router_n`.

Comment: @PSkocik You mean, using calloc?

Comment: Yes. Or `malloc` or `alloca` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `struct` can't be created with a variable length array.  Otherwise different instances of the `struct` could potentially be different sizes, which is not allowed.  There is a construct called a flexible array member which is allowed, but only for the last field in a `struct`.

The way you attempted to set things up isn't correct anyway from the perspective of the data format.  You have an array of router IDs, but the diagram shows groups of a router ID followed by two ports, a cost, and an IP address.  With this setup, you actually could use a flexible array member as follows:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) router {
    uint16_t ID;
    uint16_t port1;
    uint16_t port2;
    uint16_t cost;
    uint32_t IP_addr;
};

struct __attribute__((__packed__)) INIT_HEADER {
    uint16_t rounter_n;
    uint16_t update_interval;
    struct router routers[];
};
```

You can then take an unsigned byte array and cast it to a pointer to this struct.

Keep in mind however that, assuming this data structure is received over a network, you'll most likely need to call `ntohs` and `ntohl` on each of the `uint16_t` and `uing32_t` fields respectively in order to extract the proper values.

Also, as was mentioned in other answers, by doing this you run the risk of the structure not matching up exactly with the received data due to padding in the `struct`.

For more details on structure packing, see [this guide](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

Comment: Yes. I know. I have put a BUILD_BUG_ON for that. Would taking offsets be a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

VLAs are not valid as part of a structure. GCC has an extension for this (known as VLAIS if you want to search for it and controversies around it) but as far as I know it's only valid for structure types declared with block scope inside a function, and the size is not taken from a struct member but rather from some expression evaluated at the time the struct comes into scope (e.g. based on local variables in the function).

In any case, the approach you're taking is not portable and not good style. clang/LLVM does not (and will not, they refuse to, for arguably very good reasons) support VLAIS, and "packed" structs are not portable and have lots of pitfalls anyway. From a style/best-practices standpoint, you should just write proper serialize/deserialize functions to process the data stream rather than trying to treat external data as if it were a C type.

Comment: @R You mean, by setting offsets?